# Angular BehaviorSubject Subscribe. Call method in component after user login and logout

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have an angular layout with the header and footer. I want to update the loading of the navigation menus based on the user's role like readonly or analyst. I saw a post here on SO and copied the `BehaviorSubject` code for the header component to subscribe to a boolean change in a service. This works but I only got the one login button to change to the sign out button. In my header component ts code, I have a method that will load the menus based on the user's role. It take a list of the menu path and load only the menu items that is appropriate for the user's role. So, in addition to using `*ngIf` to changing hiding base on the subscribed boolean value change, is there a way to call a method from the subscribed change when the header component is notified by the emitted change?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my header component ts code so far:

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/Home', title: 'Home', icon: '', class: '', role: 'all'},

  // admin
  { path: '/change-role', title: 'Change Role', icon: '', class: '', role: 'admin'},
  { path: '/users', title: 'User', icon: '', class: '', role: 'admin'},
  { path: '/products', title: 'products', icon: '', class: '', role: 'admin'},
  { path: '/admin', title: 'Admin', icon: '', class: '', role: 'admin'},
];

  constructor(private dataSharingService: DataSharingService, private loginService: LoginService, private router : Router)  { 
      this.dataSharingService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( value => { this.isUserLoggedIn = value })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getLoginStatus();
    this.loadMenus();

  }

  loadMenus()
  {
      var role = this.loginService.getUserRole();
      if (role == 'admin') {
        this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem.role == 'admin');
      }
      else if (role == 'analyst' || role == 'reviewer') {
        this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem.role == 'reviewer');
      }
      else if (role == ' readOnly') {
        this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem.role == 'readOnly');
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to do.

```
this.subscription = this.dataSharingService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => {
  this.isUserLoggedIn = value;
  this.loadMenus();
});

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

The `unsubscribe` is very important here to prevent a memory leak:

- The service is a singleton (one instance for the whole app lifetime)
- The `BehaviorSubject` lasts forever too because it's in the service
- The `BehaviorSubject` holds a subscription in the form of a callback. That callback has a reference to `this`
- `this` is the current instance of the component class

In short, if you don't `unsubscribe` in the `ngOnDestroy` hook, the instance of the component's class will remain forever, taking memory even if the actual component has been destroyed in the UI.